# ggplot legend key color and items

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

Using the following data frame:

```
sdf<-data.frame(hours=gl(n=3,k=1,length=9,labels=c(0,2,4)),    
                count=c(4500,1500,2600,4000,800,200,1500,50,20),
                machine=gl(n=3,k=3,length=9,labels=c("A","B","C")))
```

The following graph can be produced using either of these scripts:

```
ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine))+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="A",])+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="B",])+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="C",])

ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine))+
  geom_area(position="dodge")
```

[image]

However, when the fill color is changed, the item in the legend disappears.

```
ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine))+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="A",])+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="B",],fill="darkorchid")+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="C",])
```

[image]

Ideally, the legend should show the color change.

Question: What script can create items in a legend as well as offer color controls for those items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the values assigned to any aesthetic using `scale_`X`_manual(values=`(whatever)`)`. Here you want `scale_fill_manual`.

```
ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine))+
  geom_area(position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "darkorchid", "green"))
```

[image]

Note that, as a rule, you want to let `ggplot` group the data for you, as you have done in your second `ggplot` call (This is what the `group` argument does). Supplying each 'slice' of data separately, as you have done in your first example, pretty much defeats the purpose of `ggplot2`, and should be avoided.

Comment: So thank you for answering this question! I'll probably make another question to ask how to vary these graphs individually. I'd like to know how to use alpha=0.5 on the graph for Machine B, but not the others.

Comment: Same principle: `... + scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 0.5, 1))`

Comment: Using  ...+ scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 0.5, 1)) unfortunately does not change any of the alpha values in this example.

Comment: My bad: I forgot to mention that you _also_ need to specify an `alpha` mapping in the `ggplot` call: `aes(x=hours,y=count, group=machine, fill=machine, alpha=machine)`. Essentially you are first telling ggplot2 that the alpha values will depend on the data in the `machine` column, and then you are telling ggplot exactly how they should correspond (i.e. level `A` gets alpha of 1, level `B` gets 0.5, etc)